# Is it possible to query a synonym with "where" clause?

Tags: oracle10g

Is it possible to query a synonym with "where" clause?
Example : Select * from Server_info where sid='123456';
Server_info is synonym.
Server_info is sysnonym for table server_details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is certainly possible, provided a table named server_details actually exists and you have been granted select right on it (or it belongs to you).

```
create table server_detail (
  a number
);

create synonym server_info for server_detail;

insert into server_info values (1);

select * from server_info;
```